# Why does IndexSet say that a new element is inserted even though the element is already in the set?

Tags: swift, set

Using `Set`s, I can conveniently insert an element into the set, and also check whether the element was in the set using one call to `insert`:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,4,2,5,3,6,7,1]
var set = Set<Int>()
for item in array {
    // set.insert not only inserts the item, but also tells me whether the item was in set before the insert
    if set.insert(item).inserted {
        print("Encountered new item: \(item)")
    } else {
        print("\(item) has already been encountered!")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Encountered new item: 1
Encountered new item: 2
Encountered new item: 3
Encountered new item: 4
4 has already been encountered!
2 has already been encountered!
Encountered new item: 5
3 has already been encountered!
Encountered new item: 6
Encountered new item: 7
1 has already been encountered!
```

However, if I rewrite the the same logic using `IndexSet`:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,4,2,5,3,6,7,1]
var set = IndexSet()
for item in array {
    // set.insert not only inserts the item, but also tells me whether the item was in set before the insert
    if set.insert(item).inserted {
        print("Encountered new item: \(item)")
    } else {
        print("\(item) has already been encountered!")
    }
}
```

The output becomes:

```
Encountered new item: 1
Encountered new item: 2
Encountered new item: 3
Encountered new item: 4
Encountered new item: 4
Encountered new item: 2
Encountered new item: 5
Encountered new item: 3
Encountered new item: 6
Encountered new item: 7
Encountered new item: 1
```

It appears that the tuple returned by `IndexSet.insert` always matches `(true, _)`, but even so, the set's `count` is not increased. I must check `set.contains(item)` before `insert` to produce the desired output.

**Question:** Is this intended behaviour for `IndexSet`?

I know that `IndexSet` is a Cocoa API, and not native to Swift, so I thought perhaps there is some special semantics that `IndexSet` has about what it means for two numbers to be "the same" that I'm not aware of. I also looked for [bug reports](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-14192?jql=text%20%7E%20%22indexset%22) on bugs.swift.org about `IndexSet`, but I didn't find anything about `insert` always returning true.

Comment: Not related to your question but why not simply `if set.insert(item).inserted {`

Comment: @LeoDabus Gosh... I feel stupid now. I was probably thinking about Haskell when writing that...

Comment: That is a really weird behavior. I have no idea why IndexSet always return true but works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IndexSet` is a the Swift value overlay type for `NSIndexSet` and `NSMutableIndexSet`. As can be seen in the implementation in [IndexSet.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/IndexSet.swift), all operations on the `IndexSet` are forwarded to  `NS(Mutable)IndexSet`.

```
// Temporary boxing function, until we can get a native Swift type for NSIndexSet
@inline(__always)
mutating func _applyMutation<ReturnType>(_ whatToDo : (NSMutableIndexSet) throws -> ReturnType) rethrows -> ReturnType {

    // ...
}
```

Apparently that does not allow to determine if an inserted already exists, this is marked as “TODO” in the source code:

```
/// Insert an integer into the `IndexSet`.
@discardableResult
public mutating func insert(_ integer: Element) -> (inserted: Bool, memberAfterInsert: Element) {
    _applyMutation { $0.add(integer) }
    // TODO: figure out how to return the truth here
    return (true, integer)
}
```

So `IndexSet.insert(value)` calls `NSMutableIndexSet.add(value)`, which adds the new value to the index set if it is not present. It behaves correctly in so far as the indices are *unique,* but the `inserted` return value is always `true`.

Comment: Ah, so `NSMutableIndexSet` did not allow us to determine whether the element is inserted in the first place. A simple way to "return the truth" is to simply count the number of elements in the set before and after the insertion, right? Or will that not work/be not optimal for some reason?

Comment: @Sweeper: Yes, NSMutableIndexSet does not return that information. – I don't know how efficient that would be since the Objective-C Foundation types are not open source. You can file a bug report.